# How to unbind default bindings from a widget

Tags: widget, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

I'm having a hard time understating how to unbind events.

I know the basic on unbinding your own binds

```
bind .c <Up> {magic code}
bind .c <Up> {}
```

I really want to know how to remove binds from pre-binded widget.

example the Text widget comes with the up key bond to move up, how do I remove that? 
So when the user hits the key nothing happen.

And is there a way to remove all binds from a widget? (no particle reason just want to know.)

And I Read that this should work, for unbind a single bind

```
 bind all <Up> {}
```

("Up" is the up arrow key for OS X)

but it didn't for me. :(

Sorry if this seem like a dumb questions but bind has been tripping me up lately. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tk has different binding classes (called “bindtags”) that it attaches its bindings to. By default, each widget has:

1. The bindtag with the same name as the widget. These are the normal ones for application code.
2. The bindtag with the same name as the class of the widget (e.g., `Button` for a button, `Canvas` for a canvas). These are usually left to Tk's defaults; removing things from here will likely break other parts of your code.
3. The bindtag with the same name as the toplevel containing the widget (except for toplevels). These are for per-dialog hotkeys, that sort of thing.
4. The global bindtag, `all`. These handle a few “backstop” things but are not usually used.

Only at most one binding from each bindtag is used; Tk prefers to use the most specific one.

Removing a binding from one bindtag does not mean that the event will not be processed; a binding on another bindtag might still pick it up. Trying to hack around the other bindtags to fool the code is not going to be satisfactory. However, if a binding on one tag finishes with a `break`, it prevents further bindtags from being tried; it terminates processing early. This makes it easy to mask specific events:

```
bind .c <Up> break
```

Tk uses this sort of masking trick in a few places inside itself…